# How to remotely monitor health of android device?

Tags: android, android-hardware

We have an Enterprise Android app, which runs on hundreds on Android devices.

App is an important part of our business operation.
It intensively uses GPS, 3G network (HTTP to server) & Display.
It runs for at least 12 hours a day.

We have certain reports that point towards hardware malfunction of some devices.

Right now, we are monitoring content of `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` for battery and `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` for network state.

Important points for us:

1. Hardware health
2. Battery health, level
3. Network state
4. GPS and display

Questions:

1. What all should be (or can be) monitored in order to ascertain health of the devices?
2. How to monitor hardware health of a device? Is it possible?

Devices are not rooted and run Android 2.2

Edit: Issue is not with app crashes. We are using Crittercism and ACRA for crash reporting. There are very few crashes now.

Comment: What is the problem? I think you have your working solution, thats why I am asking? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Right now we are only monitoring some of battery and network states. I would like to know how can we monitor hardware health, most importantly. Plus additional things which can be monitored for GPS, display.

Comment: What are the attributes of hardware health... I mean what do you mean about hardware health..

Comment: I am not aware what attributes can be gathered. A part of question is what useful attributes can be monitored. E.g. sometimes devices just freeze, their display get stuck at a screen.